# Sum multiple columns using DAX in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have multiple columns containing numeric data which I would like to sum them all up in a measure.

Output would be a measure that sums all my specified columns.

Columns: STUDY LEAVE hours, Annual Leave hours, Unpaid Leave hours etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
Total Leave Hours = SUM('Table'[Study Leave Hours]) + SUM('Table'[Annual Leave Hours]) + SUM('Table'[Unpaid Leave Hours])
```

Or, do a measure for each of the types of hours above (such as `Total Study Leave Hours = SUM('Table'[Study Leave Hours])`), and then add the 3 individual measures together:

```
Total Leave Hours = [Total Study Leave Hours] + [Total Annual Leave Hours] + [Total Unpaid Leave Hours]
```

Comment: Thanks @Leonard. That worked well. The only issue I now have is to Sum a column grouped by 2 columns which I will use a measure to subtract from.

My end goal would be to calculate utilization:

Sum of Billable Hours / (Available Hours in month) - Sum of time-off hours) which I would filter down by Business Unit & Practice.

Comment: How do you mean "grouped by 2 columns"? Measures aren't columns, so you can do some very powerful tricks with them (using CALCULATE for example). I'd recommend working on each component measure independently & then combining them into a 4th measure. Do ask if you have a question about a specific measure (sample tables/data are always helpful too)

Comment: I managed to sort it out. Thanks Leonard. I needed to group the data then do calculations on it which worked out.

Comment: @Leonard, For Step 1 how do you account for Blank values?

Comment: For a SUM like this question, BLANK is treated like a 0, so you likely don't need to do anything. If BLANK has a value other than 0, or if you're doing divisions or multiplications, you'd want to test for blanks using ISBLANK, and then handle them in a way that makes sense for your specific situation.